# I have styles components and want to migrate to scss,

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have a styles component like that and want to use the scss module.

How would I convert

```
background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.secondary};
padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.switchPadding} 0;
```

to scss. It's I need mixins or anything, please give an example.

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.secondary};
  padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.switchPadding} 0;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

theme.ts

```
  export const Theme= {
    primary: '#fff',
    secondary: '#000',
 switchPadding: '3px',
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to move all your styled-components to SCSS? Or just this particular one? Or some other alternative that I'm not seeing?

Comment: All the styled components i nede to move to separe files, like:
navbar.module.scss

I just don't know how to convert those type to work in scss instead of styled

Answer (score 0):

Material UI uses a javascript-based style solution (JSS) instead of a CSS pre-processor like SCSS.

This means its not possible to customize the Material UI theme via SCSS variables. Nor is it possible to access the theme in your CSS/SCSS styles.

Comment: I do not use Material UI. The ```theme``` is component  
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
Im using the ThemeProvider in a context